# Flutter + Php + Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mobile, flutter

Bom, sou novo no flutter mas basicamente estou fazendo um cadastro simples com 3 campos.

Resumindo meu problema é que consigo realizar o cadastro normalmente pelo emulador do AndroidStudio, mas quando gero o APK e tento cadastrar pelo meu celular ele não realiza o cadastro.

1 - Estou usando o servidor local Xampp, 2 - Coloquei o IP fixo do meu notebook na url. 3 - Consigo acessar o meu servidor e ver os arquivos através do navegador do celular moralmente(inclusive ele insere na tabela quando acesso os dados pelo navegador do celular).

Segue meu código de conexão abaixo:

```
_InserirDados() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.103/flutter/inserir.php");
    http.post(url,
        body: {
          "nome" : nometxt.text,
          "email" : emailtxt.text,
          "password" : passwordtxt.text
        });
        HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    
    
        
  }
```

Meu inserir.php

```
<?php

    include("database.php");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $res = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (User_username, User_Login, User_Password) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$password')");
    
    $res->execute();

    if ($res) {
        echo(json_encode(array("code" => 1, "mensagem" => "Inserido com sucesso")));
    }else {
        echo(json_encode(array("code" => 2, "mensagem" => "Falha na insersão dos dados.")));    
    }



?>
```

Comment: É o tipo de problema que dificilmente vai ter ajuda aqui pois é não há uma situação clara de erro. Somente observando o retorno do seu servidor e o tratamento no App você conseguirá descobrir o problema.

Answer (score -1):

A pergunta está com um escopo bem amplo.

Mas vai algumas dicas:

- Testar primeiro o seu endpoint, com um Postman por exemplo, se tiver tudo Ok, é hora de testar o aplicativo;
- Testar o aplicativo pela sua IDE (acho VS Code o melhor para Flutter), e;
- Testar o Apk gerado.

Verifique também se você você setou a permissão para acesso a internet no AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Eu sei que já faz tempo e você já deve ter até resolvido, mas como tenho uma pista dessa situação e outros podem precisar aqui vai meu palpite.

O Flutter tem o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml em 3 localizações (falando de quem desenvolve para android): android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml;
android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml.

Pois bem, nesses dois arquivos o Flutter já insere a tag:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

O Flutter precisa disso para funcionar com packages que são orientados para a web - por exemplo.

Mas é necessário fazer o mesmo quando se gera o apk, e para isso é necessário fazer a mesma observação no - mesmo arquivo - mas na pasta:

android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Nesse arquivo deve ser inserido:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Ai, o acesso à web vai funcionar quando se publica o App.

Um abração.